# Angular 2.0 Demo Tutorial - Explanation

Tags: service, angular

I am following up the Heros tutorial from angular 2.0 section.5 services.

The documentation says its not necessary to wrap the this.heroes inside a function

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
```

which doesnt work. and getting error as

```
 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHeroes' of undefined(…)
```

Whereas if i use onInit then it works (the completion of the section).

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { 

    }
     ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }
    getHeroes() {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }
```

Why i am getting the result only while running under ngOnInit?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the component class is a kind of toolbox, where you define properties and methods.

Methods will then respond to Angular hooks - like `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngOnInit` - or to events, like `click()`.

Sometimes components need to load data when they are instanciated, in which case you can use `ngOnInit` or `constructor` to call your loading method.

You do not directly call methods in your class definition. I think that if you did, it could be an issue when importing a class, or when extending a class.

You don't want the class to go fetch your data each time you import your class; rather, you want to have complete control over when your data will be imported.

---

Here are the [best practices for Angular 2](https://angular.io/styleguide)